# Does a switch statement or an if statement cost less in resource?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a 2D engine in c++ and I know that an `if` statement costs less in terms of CPU usage than a `switch` statement; but, is the difference between a `switch` statement and an `if` statement negligible with modern PC and even on mobile porting, or must I avoid `switch` at all costs?

Comment: Hopefully you're not engaging in premature optimisation here.  If in doubt, _measure_.  If you can't measure a difference, you're probably looking for efficiency gains in the wrong place.

Comment: how do you know that `if` costs less than `switch case`? Normally a series of `if`is is much costlier than a `switch case` which is often simply a jump table

Comment: I is what the teachers told about that, but it just confirm that : that kind of detail is to verify.. But they maybe right with very old compiler... Some of my teachers are there since more than 20 years, and teach exactly the same things than they did 2X years ago

Answer (score 6):

Optimisers have come a long way in the last couple decades.  It's not *normally* worth guessing which of these things will make a difference - just write your code to be as clean, understandable and maintainable as possible, then run a profiler to get meaningful feedback to guide optimisation.

That said, if you feel you must guess at this - here's some general advice...

If you have one condition, then just use `if`/`else` (or a `?` `:` pair where applicable).

If you have multiple conditions, and want control over the order in which they're tested because you have insight that lets you put the most probable branch at the top, then do so with `if`/[`else`], or - better - run a profiler and feed back branch prediction information to the optimiser when recompiling.

If you have a lot of values to test the same expression against, use a `switch` - the compiler's more likely to create some kind of dispatch table or binary branch tree that should out-perform a long, flat `if`/`else if`/... chain.